# Total Sum of Squares (TSS) - Exponential Regression

Tags: regression, anova, mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution, sums-of-squares

The total sum of squares is expressed as below [1][2],

\begin{align}
\rm{TSS} &= MSS + ESS
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\overline{y})^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{y}_{i}-\overline{y})^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})^2 
\end{align}

I have a set of exponentially distributed data (x,y) as below,

```
x   y       
332 7.283650
342 7.231924
356 6.949199
369 7.360927
369 7.154024
315 7.379831
334 7.278457
339 7.217902
321 7.238676
300 7.282819
330 7.255710
329 7.126188
374 7.042991
353 7.292686
335 7.405174
360 7.196402
351 7.130031
357 7.218629
348 6.991577
327 7.326131
347 7.453576
335 7.292167
391 7.199726
351 7.310863
307 7.206269
349 7.125773
340 7.129408
341 7.093262
358 7.375157
306 7.516519
301 7.304112
342 7.133147
350 7.345347
333 7.546433
318 7.192559
321 7.142807
347 7.167319
327 7.197025
352 7.122761
343 7.194221
314 10.388952
332 7.425843
344 8.922770
367 7.209697
361 7.040914
309 7.236910
322 7.050262
321 7.974467
291 12.036381
264 10.103215
322 7.208139
313 8.114479
374 7.072074
343 7.376195
333 7.081941
356 7.061375
351 7.176979
349 7.145715
348 6.948888
299 13.043680
337 7.679382
331 7.025437
387 7.182068
349 7.174590
293 7.387724
335 7.240338
330 7.540512
321 9.081374
350 8.787224
270 12.606609
283 8.027543
336 7.113309
346 7.149870
317 10.554307
308 8.318993
317 7.115282
347 7.038421
309 7.059298
344 7.025853
339 7.194532
262 12.690118
291 9.464123
317 12.085718
335 7.581643
348 7.195571
231 8.631216
274 7.765591
298 12.136716
221 8.449553
190 11.299447
285 7.610830
250 9.075558
372 6.836608
312 9.058835
296 6.974543
332 7.381492
298 7.987658
312 7.734847
316 6.975374
227 13.573608
305 9.040347
280 8.783381
362 7.320523
311 6.930607
222 9.994258
299 10.843992
256 9.309050
294 9.304895
303 11.077899
181 14.128775
206 11.550493
293 8.223747
315 8.525272
289 10.906415
279 8.296662
259 9.490090
305 8.418497
267 9.286926
326 8.573466
320 7.391983
20  46.517206
18  46.796088
50  33.885254
10  53.022687
50  33.730700
46  33.914648
30  39.763380
50  34.076680
40  40.189545
66  27.821829
39  40.119954
39  39.077237
57  27.396287
29  46.103090
30  39.334099
29  40.155373
30  40.455963
47  33.197760
60  39.389356
29  40.129821
40  40.059608
38  39.861015
30  46.634160
19  45.749527
47  33.575315
68  33.705149
69  33.255718
69  33.722495
10  52.855150
18  46.515025
28  40.819288
28  39.971840
20  47.167931
28  41.367704
50  34.006985
49  33.528368
50  33.917452
39  39.867870
50  33.280126
40  39.621913
20  46.517206
18  46.796088
50  33.885254
10  53.022687
50  33.730700
46  33.914648
30  39.763380
50  34.076680
40  40.189545
66  27.821829
39  40.119954
39  39.077237
57  27.396287
29  46.103090
30  39.334099
29  40.155373
30  40.455963
47  33.197760
60  39.389356
29  40.129821
40  40.059608
38  39.861015
30  46.634160
19  45.749527
47  33.575315
68  33.705149
69  33.255718
69  33.722495
10  52.855150
18  46.515025
28  40.819288
28  39.971840
20  47.167931
28  41.367704
50  34.006985
49  33.528368
50  33.917452
39  39.867870
50  33.280126
40  39.621913
20  46.517206
18  46.539745
48  33.885254
10  53.022687
50  33.730700
46  33.592453
30  39.763380
50  34.076680
40  40.189545
64  27.515942
36  40.119954
38  39.089597
56  27.260741
28  46.103090
30  39.334099
28  40.155373
30  40.455963
46  33.043622
60  39.389356
28  40.129821
40  40.059608
36  39.724430
30  46.645377
18  45.749527
46  33.307547
66  33.456388
68  33.031573
68  33.714705
10  52.855150
18  46.253489
28  40.595767
28  39.724741
20  47.167931
28  41.117905
50  34.021215
48  33.528368
50  33.917452
38  39.867870
50  33.280126
40  39.621913
```

I am trying

a) to find the MSS, ESS and TSS values.
 b) validate if the values I got are correct, satisfying TSS = MSS + ESS

### Approach 1

[Best Fit approach [3], Without converting the exponential data to linear data]

\begin{align}
y_{i} = y,
x_{i} = x
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\overline{y}=23.62464471
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\hat{y}_{i}=Ae^{Bx_{i}}= 47.3826e^{-0.0055x_{i}}
\end{align}
where A=exp(a) and B=b. a and b obtained from eq.(3) and eq.(4) from [3]. The equations are reproduced below,

\begin{align}
a &= (\sum_{i=1}^n ln\ y_{i} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}\ ln\ y_{i})\ /\ (n\ \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i})^2)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
b &= (n\ \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}\ ln\ y_{i} - \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \sum_{i=1}^n ln\ y_{i})\ /\ (n\ \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i})^2)
\end{align}

Calculating the values,

\begin{align}
MSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{y}_{i}-\overline{y})^2 = 55961.58373
\end{align}
\begin{align}
ESS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})^2 = 1739.728157
\end{align}
\begin{align}
TSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\overline{y})^2 &= 62029.58951
\end{align}

Unfortunately MSS + ESS = 57701.31189 != TSS

### Approach 2

[Best Fit approach [3], Converting the exponential data to linear data]

\begin{align}
y_{i} = ln y,
x_{i} = x
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\overline{y}=2.868328
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\hat{y}_{i}=a+{bx_{i}}= 3.858255231{-0.0055x_{i}}
\end{align}
where a and b obtained from eq.(3) and eq.(4) from [3]. The equations are reproduced below,

\begin{align}
a &= (\sum_{i=1}^n ln\ y_{i} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}\ ln\ y_{i})\ /\ (n\ \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i})^2)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
b &= (n\ \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}\ ln\ y_{i} - \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \sum_{i=1}^n ln\ y_{i})\ /\ (n\ \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i})^2)
\end{align}

Calculating the values,

\begin{align}
MSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{y}_{i}-\overline{y})^2 = 150.6993684 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
ESS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})^2 = 3.992417623
\end{align}
\begin{align}
TSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\overline{y})^2 &= 154.691786
\end{align}

Here we able to validate, MSS + ESS = 154.691786 = TSS

### Approach 3

[Least Square Fit approach [3], Without converting the exponential data to linear data]

\begin{align}
y_{i} = y,
x_{i} = x
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\overline{y}=23.62464471
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\hat{y}_{i}=Ae^{Bx_{i}}= 48.6062e^{-0.0056x_{i}}
\end{align}
where A=exp(a) and B=b. a and b obtained from eq.(9) and eq.(10) from [3]. The equations are reproduced below,

\begin{align}
a &= (\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}^2 y_{i}) \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}\ ln\ y_{i}) - \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}) \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}y_{i}\ ln\ y_{i}))\ /\ ((\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}^2 y_{i}))-(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}))
\end{align}

\begin{align}
b &= (\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}\ ln\ y_{i}) - \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}) \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}\ ln\ y_{i}))\ /\ ((\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}^2 y_{i}))-(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}))
\end{align}

Calculating the values,

\begin{align}
MSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{y}_{i}-\overline{y})^2 = 59282.06044
\end{align}
\begin{align}
ESS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})^2 = 1622.208368
\end{align}
\begin{align}
TSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\overline{y})^2 &= 62029.58951
\end{align}

Unfortunately MSS + ESS = 60904.26881 != TSS

### Approach 4

[Least Square Fit approach[3], Converting the exponential data to linear data]

\begin{align}
y_{i} = ln y,
x_{i} = x
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\overline{y}=2.868328
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\hat{y}_{i}=a+{bx_{i}}= 3.858255231{-0.0055x_{i}}
\end{align}
where a and b obtained from eq.(9) and eq.(10) from [3]. The equations are reproduced below,

\begin{align}
a &= (\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}^2 y_{i}) \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}\ ln\ y_{i}) - \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}) \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}y_{i}\ ln\ y_{i}))\ /\ ((\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}^2 y_{i}))-(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}))
\end{align}

\begin{align}
b &= (\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}\ ln\ y_{i}) - \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}) \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}\ ln\ y_{i}))\ /\ ((\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}^2 y_{i}))-(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i} y_{i}))
\end{align}

Calculating the values,

\begin{align}
MSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{y}_{i}-\overline{y})^2 = 155.7545382 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
ESS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})^2 = 4.053637091
\end{align}
\begin{align}
TSS = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\overline{y})^2 &= 154.691786
\end{align}

Unfortunately, MSS + ESS = 159.8081753 != TSS

Questions:

1. Is the above equation is limited to linear data only?
2. How to calculate TSS and ESS for exponentially data without converting it to linear first? The TSS equation seems to be generic that could fit any type of data.

Hope you can guide me on the right way to calculate TSS and ESS for exponential data.

```
Reference:
[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_sum_of_squares
[2] http://www.originlab.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=4823 
[3] http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html
```

Comment: Well, if you mean by exponential regression an ordinary linear regression for $Y' = \log Y$, then you need to plug into the variance decomposition formula the corresponding quantities for $Y'$ and not for $Y$.

Comment: That decomposition should work with any model that includes an additive constant term.  What, precisely, do you mean by "exponential regression" then?

Comment: @MichaelMayer and whuber -- Sorry if I was not clear. Have rewritten the query and also experimented the approach suggested by Michael Mayer. I can get the right value on the converted data i.e exponential to linear. But not on the original exponentially distributed data. Wondering why as the TSS equation seem generic. What I am missing here? I am new to statistics and doing lots of reading. Hope you would excuse me if the question is basic

Comment: I suspect you may be making some arithmetic error--it would help to show a small example *in full* so your results could be checked.  What is the distinction in your tables between `Y(measured)` and `Yi`?

Comment: @whuber Sorry for the late reply. I was travelling and just back continuing my studies. I have rewritten including a full example. Yi and Y(measured) is the same for Approach 1, but for Approach 2 Yi= ln Y(measured). Found I would need to use Approach 2 to get TSS = MSS + ESS. Confused why Approach 1 does not work as TSS equation seem generic.

Comment: The variance decomposition works for any model fitted by OLS, of course only for the transformed variables. As for averages, non-linear transformations and taking variances can't be reversed.

Comment: @MichaelMayer Do excuse me as am new to statistics.Believe when you say variance decomposition you mean the TSS = MSS + ESS relationship.You mentioned variance decomposition should work for OLS but according to [3], Approach 1 and 2 is for best fit. I have worked for the least square fitting [3],and have shared the results as Approach 3 (without converting the exp date to linear) and 4 (converting the exp date to linear) above.I find in Approach 3 and 4, the TSS = MSS + ESS relationship does not hold too.Keen to validate the variance decomposition for the least square fitting.Can you guide me?